# Word or phrase for beautiful music going unheard?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I can't think of a word or phrase describing this scenario:

> Someone is singing beautifully and it has meaning but no one is there to hear it so it is useless.

Please help!

Comment: Irony? I think it's ironical.

Comment: Sometimes you have to sing just for the sake of the song.

Comment: *Singing in vain? Lonely serenade?* Please clarify the question. What meaning does it have? Why is it useless?

Comment: Bathroom singing?

Comment: It's not quite ***Zen***, since "someone" can presumably hear *their own voice*. Unlike the tree falling down in the middle of the Amazon jungle with no-one to hear it (which I firmly believe makes no sound at all. :)

Comment: Useless Beauty? Elvis Costello thinks that's worth a song: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pi50yFMZ49E

Comment: It's the old "If a tree falls in a forest" question.

Comment: No it ain't, it's an echo of Gray: "Full many a flower is born to blush unseen, And waste its sweetness on the desert air."

Comment: Is **unfulfilled** in the right direction, or is **unperceived**?

Comment: How do you know if someone is singing beautifully, if you aren't there to hear it? And have you never sung in the shower, or in the car when no one was around? Sometimes a person sings because they feel like it. If they have a stunning voice, the voice will remain so another day. So, it's not a waste, that person is singing because  they *have to*.

Answer (score 2):

Hidden lives, and unrecognised artists are the theme of
Gray's *Elegy in a Country Churchyard*.

> Full many a flower is born to blush unseen,
>   And waste its sweetness on the desert air. (55)
>
> Along the cool sequestered vale of life
>   They kept the noiseless tenor of their way.  (75)

Comment: So which word answers the OP's question?

Comment: It could only be, "waste."

Comment: @Kristina Lopez, would you accept hidden, unrecognised, unseen, sequestered? And the ref. leads to obscure, neglected, unhonoured, unknown; and Gray's notes add 'begli occhi chiusi,' two closed eyes.

Comment: @Little Eva, mercy, mercy!

Comment: BTW, your only upvote, as I type, is mine (the quality of my mercy) ;-).  Love the lines!

Comment: That's up to the OP but as much as I love 'begli occhi chiusi,' two closed eyes, they're not actually in your answer!  Just trying to help! :-)

Comment: +1 for both sequestered (which answers the first part of the OP's question) and the whole quotation (which answers the whole question even though it's longer than a phrase) :-). I would still include a link to a dictionary definition for *sequestered* and acknowledge the fact that David Pugh thought of the same poem at about the same time as you did (you might have not noticed it, it's in the comments to the OP) :-)

Answer (score 0):

When someone is doing something 'obliviously', it's another way to say that they continue doing that without any concern or awareness of what is happening around them.

So you could say 'she was singing obliviously' or 'singing beautifully, but oblivious to her environment'.